# A query that contains a UNION of two SELECTS

Tags: oracle11g

A query that contains a UNION of two SELECTS that contain the columns
LOCATION_ID,STREET_ADDRESS,CITY,COUNTRY_NAME and "No of Depts". The result must be a list of ALL
locations with the number of departments in the location. The list must be ordered from the highest to the lowest
number of departments.

```
SELECT locations.location_id, 
       locations.street_address, 
       locations.city, 
       locations.country_id 
FROM locations,departments
WHERE (locations.location_id = departments.location_id)
GROUP BY locations.location_id, 
         locations.street_address, 
         locations.city, 
         locations.country_id
UNION ALL
SELECT Count(departments.department_name) 
FROM departments
WHERE (locations.location_id = departments.location_id)
GROUP BY departments.department_id, departments.location_id
ORDER BY (departments.department_name) DESC;`
```

Comment: i have an error on this code! im using the Oracle HR database!

Comment: And the error would be?

Comment: Union all only works if both queries have the same columns, you have two queries that are completely different. Union all just adds the rows from two queries together, you seem to want to an extra column. You will have to include that in your first SELECT clause.

Answer (score 1):

Why doesn't this work?

```
  SELECT count() as c, 
         departments.department_name, 
         locations.location_id, 
         locations.street_address, 
         locations.city, 
         locations.country_id 
  FROM locations
  join departments ON locations.location_id = departments.location_id
  GROUP BY departments.department_name, locations.location_id, locations.street_address, locations.city, locations.country_id
```

Comment: Union all works if i have the same ammount of columns? so im my case i have like 4 columns selected in my first select clause and only one in the second select clause! so this is the reason that i have an erros?

Comment: and how im supposed to select LOCATION_ID,STREET_ADDRESS,CITY that belongs to LOCATION table and the country name that belongs to COUNTRY table?

Comment: @user2985600 - I am totally not clear on your requirements.  This gets all the fields but the country, for that just join to what you want....

Comment: @user2985600 - the answer to your question is right in this answer. The keyword is `JOIN`. What you seem to think `UNION` does, is actually what `JOIN` does for you. just relax and look at the code above :)